# Why lastIndexOf() works and search() does not?

Tags: javascript

I was trying my hand at editing a given string to remove the file extension at the end by using a combination of slice() and search(). However, when using search(), the var vNamePrepared would come up empty.

```
function site_change() {
  var vDocGrabber = "indexmobile.html",
      vNamePrepared = vDocGrabber.slice(0, vDocGrabber.search("."));
  /*transform vNamePrepared in some way*/
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vNamePrepared + ".php";}
```

Alternatively, that exact code with search() replaced by lastIndexOf() produced the desired result.

```
function site_change() {    
  var vDocGrabber = "indexmobile.html",
      vNamePrepared = vDocGrabber.slice(0, vDocGrabber.lastIndexOf("."));
  /*transform vNamePrepared in some way*/
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vNamePrepared + ".php";}

--> indexmobile.php
```

For what reason would search() not work here? Would it not return the index of the period as an integer into slice()?

First question, apologies if it's not up to standard.

Comment: More info on [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: There is no `String.search(String)`, closest would be `String.includes(String)`, which doesn't return an index either

Comment: @adeneo the string is converted to a regex in [String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Comment: @DenysSéguret - you're right, anything that goes in that isn't a regex is put through `new RegExp(whatever)`, but the OP doesn't seem to want a regex, but to actually search for the string `"."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`search` accepts a regular expression, and `.` matches any non-newline character in a regular expression. The equivalent to `lastIndexOf` starting from the beginning is `indexOf`.

Answer (score 2):

It is processing the "." as a regex.

To escape the ".":

```
vDocGrabber.search('\\.')
```

Answer (score -3):

Personally I never use .search method since i've come up with bugs on different browsers

Instead i rely upon .indexOf since it has better support, here's a little help from the infamous [w3 site](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)